# Windows 10 osk.exe not showing up automatically

Tags: qt, windows-10, qml, qt5, on-screen-keyboard

I am creating a QML (Qt 5.12.5, Windows 10) application that needs to open Windows 10 keyboard (osk or tabtip) automatically when a text field has the focus.

However, the keyboard does not appear automatically. And I notice that it does not appear automatically in other applications like Notepad neither.

So is it a bug with Windows 10 or is there something to do to automatically open that keyboard when an application needs it?

I precise that I tried to enable / disable the tablet / desktop modes, and enable / disable the option, in Device / Typing, "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached".

Comment: While it'd definitely be better to find a native Win10 solution, as an alternative you could check ou the Qt [Virtual Keyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html) add-on (it's selectable in the Qt installers as an extra package). It's not perfect but does work.

Comment: I cannot use Qt Virtual Keyboard in my application due to the license.

Comment: I've just tested in my Asus T101HA with Windows 10 home 1903, and detaching the screen from the keyboard, in both desktop and tablet mode, touching the edit area of windows notepad triggers the opening of the OSK. It may be a bug in windows, drivers or maybe you can't disconnect the physical keyboard or windows thinks that it is always connected.